# Why does Throwable.class.getClassLoader() return null?

Tags: java, classloader

Why does `Throwable.class.getClassLoader()` return null?
Is there some hidden knowledge?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29) states

> Returns the class loader for the class. **Some implementations may use
>   null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return
>   null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap
>   class loader.**

So the `Throwable` class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader in your JVM implementation.